# Confused with: course_running.add_student(self)

Tags: python, oop

Could anyone help with my understanding, please? I don't understand what is happening with this line or why it works : `course_running.add_student(self)`.

I thought this was an OOP concept but could anyone help make this clearer?

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, student_number):
        self.name = name
        self.student_number = student_number
        self.classes = []

    def enrol(self, course_running):
        self.classes.append(course_running)
        course_running.add_student(self)

class CourseRunning:
    def __init__(self, course, year):
        self.course = course
        self.year = year
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)
```

Answer (score 1):

`course_running` is an object of class `CourseRunning` and `course_running.add_student(self)` is calling a method of it's class named `add_student` which is appending the student to `students` list.

Answer (score 1):

Your `enrol()` function in the `Student` class is taking two parameters: **`self`** and `course_running`.

**`self` is the instance of your current class (`Student`)**.

That's why in your `add_student()` function (which takes also two parameters: `self` (the current instance of the `CourseRunning` class) and `student` (which is simply an **instance of a `Student`**)).

That's why you can pass the **`self`** from `enrol()` as **`student`** in `add_student()`.

Comment: If I "pass self from enrol() as student in add_student()", doesn't it append the list with an object. This is where i'm getting confused. If i'm putting an object into a list how is that useful?